# what is the equivalent R code for this experiment?

Tags: r, probability

Estimate the probability that the sum of five dice is between 15 and 20, inclusive.

my attempt:

```
myex<-replicate(100,{
   #creat a vector of 5 die
   mydie <- sample(1:6, 5, replace= T)
   #sum the value of all 6 die
   sum = mydie[1]+mydie[2]+mydie[3]+mydie[4]+mydie[5]
})
#mean with the conditions
mean(myex >=15 & myex<=20)
```

am i wrong?

Comment: You don't need `mydie[1] + mydie[2] + ...`, you can use `sum(mydie)`

Comment: Or may also use `mean(between(colSums(matrix(sample(1:6, 5 * 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 100)), 15, 20))`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the exact probability by enumerating all possibilities

```r
all_possible <- rowSums(do.call(expand.grid, lapply(1:5, \(x) 1:6)))
```

Which looks like this:

```r
hist(all_possible)
```

[image]

Now we just count the number of these values that are between 15 and 20.

```r
sum(all_possible >= 15 & all_possible <= 20)/length(all_possible)
#> [1] 0.5570988
```

To get an *estimate* of this value, we can get a sample of 5 independent dice rolls 1000 times like this instead, then use the same code to get the probability of finding the sum between 15 and 20:

```r
samp <- replicate(1000, sum(sample(6, 5, TRUE)))

hist(samp)
```

[image]

```r
sum(samp >= 15 & samp <= 20)/length(samp)
#> [1] 0.554
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That would be a good way to check but it really sidesteps the question which was asking for a simulation estimate.

Comment: @IRTFM fair enough. I have added in a simulation too.

Comment: Yes. That’s a nice side-by-side comparison of theory and simulation.